# Getting SMTPServerDisconnected error sending email through python

Tags: python, smtp, starttls, smtps

When trying to send the email with the host:cpanel.freehosting.com
P it is raising an error like

This is my code:

```
import smtplib
s = smtplib.SMTP('cpanel.freehosting.com', 465)
s.starttls()
s.login("myusername", "mypassword")
message = "Message_you_need_to_send"
s.sendmail("myemailid", "receiver_email_id", message)
s.quit()
```

This is the error i got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 337, in connect
(code, msg) = self.getreply()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 393, in getreply
  raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

Comment: Your best bet will be to check with the service provider, ie "does your SMTP server require TLS? Is 465 port the correct port?" etc. I also doubt that this is the correct server url

Comment: There's quite a bit that goes into making a mail server work. MX Records, Reverse DNS, whitelisting, routing concerns, etc. Are you sure that `cpanel.freehosting.com` is your mail server, for instance?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the port number you are using I'd try with `SMTP_SSL` instead of `SMTP` and `starttls()`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html:

> An SMTP_SSL instance behaves exactly the same as instances of SMTP.
>   SMTP_SSL should be used for situations where SSL is required from the
>   beginning of the connection and using starttls() is not appropriate.
>   If host is not specified, the local host is used. If port is zero, the
>   standard SMTP-over-SSL port (465) is used.

`STARTTLS` is a form of *opportunistic TLS*, it is supposed to be used with old protocols, that originally did't support TLS, to upgrade the connection.
The port 465 was used before the introduction of `STARTTLS` for `SMTPS`, which is now deprecated.

```
import smtplib
s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('cpanel.freehosting.com', 465)
s.login("myusername", "mypassword")
message = "Message_you_need_to_send"
s.sendmail("myemailid", "receiver_email_id", message)
s.quit()
```

Alternatively you should be able to use port 25 with your original code.

```
import smtplib
s = smtplib.SMTP('cpanel.freehosting.com', 25)
s.starttls()
s.login("myusername", "mypassword")
message = "Message_you_need_to_send"
s.sendmail("myemailid", "receiver_email_id", message)
s.quit()
```

In both examples you can completely omit the port number as you are using the default ports.